# File upload error in Asp .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have already configured all the settings **NOT** to all files more then 100kb but it still is trying to upload the file and is giving 404.13 error.

This is my web.config configuration:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits>
      <headerLimits>
        <add header="Content-type" sizeLimit="100000" />
      </headerLimits>
    </requestLimits>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>

<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="100000"></httpRuntime>
```

The code which i have written in c# is as follows:

```
        if (fuUpload.HasFile)
    {
        int fileSize = fuUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        if (fileSize > 100000)
        {
            //ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + sizeError + "');", true);
            lblSizeError.Text = "File size should be less then 100Kb";
        }
        else
        {
            fuUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/RegistrationUploads/" + fuUpload.FileName));

            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + success + "');", true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + uploadFile + "');", true);
    }
```

It is working fine for files less then 100kb and throwing error if no file has been selected.

I want it to throw and error if the size is more then 100kb.

Answer (score 0):

Set maximum file size (`102400Bytes -> 100KB`) and execution time to `1200` which by default is 360 (6 mins):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="1200" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And you can handle exception of maximum request exceed.